# Convert SmallWorld GIS topology to pgRouting topology

Tags: pgrouting, topology, smallworld-gis

Is there any way to convert SmallWorld GIS topology to the format that pgRouting use?
My costumer have use SmallWorld GIS and make his topology on it. but when he export his information as shape file, the topology is gone!

How can the topology be preserved?

Comment: Unfortunately shapefiles will not preserve topological data.

Comment: But it can use source,target and cost column to store topology like what pgRouting use.

Comment: FME will do Small World to PostGIS - Though it would be best practice to re-create topology with pgrouting.

Answer (score 2):

You can preserve the topology if you can preserve `source` and `target` attribute. The function of pgRouting to create a topology does nothing else than populate `source` and `target` columns.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that you could open the PostGIS database from inside a Smallworld session and then do the conversion with a Magik script. If its just a one way data export process that shouldn't be too complicated. Option B would be to export a csv from Smallworld with a column structure that can be directly imported into a PostGIS table.